# module.exports = xyz in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, module, typescript1.8

I have the following code approach in javascript, but I want to know what Typescript code would compile to this?

```
var MyModule= require("./module-common");

MyModule._function1 = function () {
    console.log("function 1");
};

MyModule._function2 = function () {
    console.log("function 2");
};

module.exports = MyModule;
```

I have tried

### Classes:

#### ts:

```
class myModule {
    function1(){}
}
export = myModule;
```

#### -> JS:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var myModule = (function () {
        function myModule() {
        }
        myModule.prototype.function1 = function () { };
        return myModule;
    }());
    return myModule;
});
```

### Modules:

#### ts:

```
module myModule {
    function function1(){}
}
export = myModule;
```

#### -> JS:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var myModule;
    (function (myModule) {
        function function1() { }
    })(myModule || (myModule = {}));
    return myModule;
});
```

But as you can see, neither have produced what I want...

The above examples were done using: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

but in my real project my `tsconfig` is as so:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "removeComments": false
    }, 
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules", 
        "sample"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have the module system outputting AMD modules. Can you post your tsconfig?

Comment: @Paarth I was just using [http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html), but in my project my tsconfig is shown above

Answer (score 0):

Pased on the js `define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {` clearly `compilerOptions.module` is not kicking in.

## Fix

- make sure your compiler is pointing to `-p path/to/tsconfig.json`.

Comment: As noted in the question, the examples posted didn't have a tsconfig.json, as they were done on the ts playground